# google chrome is not launching in EC2 Instance

Tags: python-3.x, linux, google-chrome, amazon-ec2, selenium-chromedriver

I want to run a simple python code in EC2 instance using google-chrome which works fine in my local system
Though I have installed all the required packages I am not able to run the script
Google Chrome 109.0.5414.119
ChromeDriver 109.0.5414.74
selenium   4.8.0

while running a below simple script

#######################

````
```
from selenium import webdriver

service = webdriver.chrome.service.Service('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
service.start()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options = options.to_capabilities()
driver = webdriver.Remote(service.service_url, options)

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```
````

###############################

I am getting the following error

#########################
`raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace) selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.            (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist) (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver     is assuming that Chrome has crashed.) Stacktrace: \#0 0x55cd3bfbd303 \<unknown\> \#1 0x55cd3bd91d37 \<unknown\> \#2 0x55cd3bdba157 \<unknown\> \#3 0x55cd3bdb6330 \<unknown\> \#4 0x55cd3bdf74a6 \<unknown\> \#5 0x55cd3bdee753 \<unknown\> \#6 0x55cd3bdc1a14 \<unknown\> \#7 0x55cd3bdc2b7e \<unknown\> \#8 0x55cd3c00c32e \<unknown\> \#9 0x55cd3c00fc0e \<unknown\> \#10 0x55cd3bff2610 \<unknown\> \#11 0x55cd3c010c23 \<unknown\> \#12 0x55cd3bfe4545 \<unknown\> \#13 0x55cd3c0316a8 \<unknown\> \#14 0x55cd3c031836 \<unknown\> \#15 0x55cd3c04cd13 \<unknown\> \#16 0x7f0f6b23e44b start_thread`

Comment: Are you using a Linux EC2 instance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are running a Linux EC2 instance. Here are the instructions for running your code on a Ubuntu Linux EC2 other OSs will be slightly different.

Either connect to you EC2 instance and run:

```
sudo snap install chromium
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.zip
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unzip -y
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip 
sudo apt install python3-pip -y
pip3 install selenium --user
```

Or add these commands to your EC2 user data:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/ubuntu
snap install chromium
wget https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.74/chromedriver_linux64.zip
apt update
apt install unzip -y
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip 
apt install python3-pip -y
sudo -u ubuntu pip3 install selenium  --user
```

Then update your script to be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=/home/ubuntu/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default")
options.add_argument('--headless')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
print(driver.page_source)
driver.quit()
```

Then run your script with python3 e.g. `python3 test.py` if your file is called `test.py`.

It will print the source of the web page requested i.e. `https://www.google.com`